# Как исправить непонятную кодировку при SELECT из ms sql

Tags: python, sql-server

Есть SQL запрос, который выполняется из скрипта python.

Проблема в том, что поле, которого нет в базе, выдает символы не utf8. Как это можно адекватно перекодировать в кириллицу? В самом питоновском скрипте или на стороне базы именно для этой переменной? Когда запрос выполняется на чистом sql, в базе все норм, отображается с кириллицей.

На питоне идет подключение к mssql через pymssql.

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN c_object_mane = '1' or c_object_mane = '2'
THEN 'Санкт-Петербург' 
WHEN c_object_mane = '3' 
THEN 'Москва'
END AS c_object_adress, an.[c_object_mane], an.[c_house_name], an.[c_type_room], an.[c_room], an.[c_status_flat], an.[lead_bujet], an.[c_an], an.[ddu_date]
FROM mssql_db as an where an.ddu_date >= '2021-01-01'
```

При выводе по логике должны нормально писать города Москва, Санкт-Петербург, но выходит только это:

```
Òþìåíü
Òþìåíü
Òþìåíü
Ìîñêâà
Òþìåíü
Òþìåíü
Òþìåíü
Òþìåíü
Òþìåíü
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, изменил подключение с pymssql на pyodbc и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию MySQL имеет кодировку latin1 на всех уровнях.

Попробуй в php:

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
```